# Failed to ping vm ip address from another device (android phone) under same network

Tags: networking, ubuntu-16.04, vmware, ping

i have network issue from using vm.

This is ifconfig info of vm ubuntu 16.04.

[image]

This is ipconfig info of my host machine.

[image]

And this is the network settings of vm.

[image]

- I able to ping vm ip addr from host machine.
- I able to ping phone ip addr from vm.
- I unable to ping vm ip addr from phone under same network.

Im bad in networking. Any of you have good clue can help me solve this issue?

Appreciate your help & Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NAT has four different types, and it always works as a firewall. That is why we need UDP traversal and hole-punch sometime. If you want other devices like host and phone build a connection to vm, you need firstly connect from vm to thoses deivces to build a "hole" as a path.

Comment: Hi Thanks for quick reply. I can ping my vm from host machine. Does that mean i still a hole in order to get accessible from phone?

Comment: I think you should read this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT_traversal for help. And if you don't want to be so complex, you can try other vm network mode like bridge. But I suggest it's better to get a deep understand of these network connection types.

Comment: Thank your info! I manage to ping my local server in vm now after changing to bridge network. It solved my problem but i still will go deep understand of these network connection types as you said. Thank again!

Comment: You're welcome. Hope you can grasp the core of vm network connection -.-